# EntitityManager not injected properly, always null

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

I have a few JPA entities that are created and persisted in JAX-RS methods. I have a worker thread that processes some data about those entities in JPA over time and while I can pass in the Entity objects, I am unable to persist any changes to them because the EntitityManager in the thread that makes the changes is always null.

The class containing my worker thread is declared as such:

```
public final class EntityService {

@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
EntityManager entityManager;
```

The EntityManager is always null and even if it's passed in from a JAX-RS method as by the time the thread gets a chance to attempt to use the EM, the EM is null as the JAX-RS method has terminated.

How can I get a valid Entity Manager into my Service pojo when injection isn't working? I'm using Hibernate and Wildfly 10

Comment: Are you using @Transactional in your save method ? EntityManager should not be null, you should have a problem is your spring configuration or the way the bean is loaded

Comment: I don't have a spring configuration, I'm not using spring. It's Wildfly. Also, the EntityService class isn't a managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

`EntityService` needs to be managed in order to have `EntityManager` injected. For example: add `@LocalBean` annotation and inject `EntityService` to the `REST` service class.

Also i'm not sure if it is good idea to make `class EntitySercice` `final`.

Comment: +1 for *Also i'm not sure if it is good idea to make `class EntitySercice` `final`*. Also, `@LocalBean` should be also [`@Stateful` otherwise `EntityManager` could not be injected as `EXTENDED`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547817/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-scoped-persistence-context-and-extend/2548617#2548617)

Comment: I do have the EntityService as final. I just forgot to include it with my minor obfuscation of my actual code when I wrote the question

Answer (score 0):

### Persistence context

In short, you can only inject an `EntityManager` into an EJB. [If you're EJB is not `Stateful`, it won't work with an `EXTENDED` persistence context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548617/4906586). Instead, you'll go with a transational one:

```
@Stateless
public class myService{

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    protected EntityManager em;

}
```

I haven't tried [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39472779/4906586) but you can annotate your REST resource as `Stateless` which will allow you to inject an `EntityManager`

### EntityManagerFactory

If you're not using EJB, then you'll need to [inject the `EntityManagerFactory` as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717196/4906586): (below is the copied code)

```
package com.test.service;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/service")
public class TestService {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "test")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @GET
    public List get() {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        try {
            // do something with entityManager
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Two remarks:

- Please note that the annotation is a `@PersistenceUnit`, not a `@PersistenceContext`
- Make sure you [close your entity manager at the end of the transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248578/4906586).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as I had omit the starter-parent from my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Although I was using `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` rather than `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION`.